# Understanding Powershell behavior

Tags: arrays, powershell, enumeration

**NOTE**: These code examples are meant to work in the PowerShell Console and NOT in the PowerShell ISE.

Why is it that in this snippet of code

Snippet #1:

```
& {Get-NetAdapter; Write-Host 'Press any key to continue...'; $X = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')}
```

the results of `Get-NetAdapter` are displayed **BEFORE** the `Write-Host` and the `ReadKey` are executed, but in this snippet of code

Snippet #2:

```
& {Get-SecretInfo; Write-Host 'Press any key to continue...'; $X = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')}
```

The results of `Get-SecretInfo` are displayed **AFTER** the `Write-Host` and the `ReadKey` are executed?

I have 2 objectives here:

1. To enable the results of `Get-SecretInfo` to display **BEFORE** the `Write-Host` and the `ReadKey` are executed
2. To understand why `Get-NetAdapter` and `Get-SecretInfo` are behaving differently, even though they both return `Object[]`?

Comment: Change `Get-SecretInfo` to `Get-SecretInfo |Out-Default` - this will make the host application wait until the output from `Get-SecretInfo` has been written to the host's UI before continuing with the next operation.

Comment: Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen for addressing the first question - fixing the core issue of execution sequencing. I am however still unable to understand the why of the situation. From my reading up on `Out-Default ` and `Out-Host` I think I understand that `Out-Default` is the DEFAULT behavior, and it in fact redirects to `Out-Host` if the view is a table view. At the core of my concern is the issue - If `Out-Default` is the default, why do I have to explicitly specify it? Is `Get-SecretInfo` broken?

Comment: This is probably the #1 faq.  Implied use of format-table is delayed for at least 2 objects.